# UITableView grouped - how to get width of cell's contentView after rotation

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview

The table resizes its width after changing between portrait and landscape mode. The table view is grouped. I need to calculate width of contentView to change width of a progress indicator.
I'm trying

```
float contentWidth = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].contentView.frame.size.width;
```

But jus after rotation it gives an old value which changes after scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
float contentWidth = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].contentView.bounds.size.width;
```

Or you can just set appropriate `autoresizingMask` for your progress indicator when configuring it:

```
progressIndicator.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about bounds and I'll check this approach also.

Answer (score 0):

You can reload the tableView after the rotation has finished using the method below:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

This should give you the newer value.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this, as soon as I get to my computer. But I noted when the table view is loaded, the content view width is less than visible width of grouped cells. Perhaps because it'loaded fron nib.